# PHP posting checkbox data

Tags: php, html, database, post, insert

I am making a survey and I want to post data to my database. But I run into a problem, if I want to post checkbox data it will only post the last checked box. Hope I can get some help, here is the code:

**html**

```
<form name="x" id="submit1" action="confirm_medici.php" method ="post" onsubmit="validator();return false;" target="_self">

<input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="Android">Android<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="Windowsphone">Windows Phone<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="opsystem" value="Ios">IOS (Apple)<br><br>
Else: <input type="text" name="opsystem" size="75"><br>
```

**php**

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("x","x","x","x");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$question1=$_POST['opsystem']; 

$sql="INSERT INTO medici (colum1)
VALUES
('$question1')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename the field so the name ends with the characters `[]`. PHP will then expose it as an array instead of dumping all but the last item.

```
name="opsystem[]"

$_POST['opsystem']
```

Comment: That's the first step, but then there's the `INSERT` with values of Array.

Comment: @ChrisForrence — Use a for loop over the array and insert each time you go around the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your checkbox is multiple choice, you can just add `[]` to the end of the checkbox name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opsystem[]" value="...">...</input>
```

And then in php:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['opsystem'];

foreach ($checkbox as $item) {
    ... Database Insertion Code For Each Checkbox Here
}
```

In the foreach you can then run a query to insert the answer into the database. Or you could implode the array instead of running a foreach over it, and insert the new string into the database.

With Implode:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['opsystem'];

$checkboxResults = implode(',', $checkbox);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO medici (column1) VALUES ('.$checkboxResults.')';
```

I will also point out that this SQL is NOT GOOD! It is open to sql injections.

Comment: I tried it, but every time I try to use the explode or forecast function I get error messages like this: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: If it is giving that error with implode, it sounds like your `$_POST` does not contain `'opsystem'. Try a `var_dump($_POST)` and make sure that `$_POST` contains the data you have sent using the form.